# Kafka configuration files `server.properties`, `controller.properties` and `broker.properties`

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka appears to ship with 3 configuration files. They are named

- `server.properties`
- `controller.properties`
- `broker.properties`

Many of the same configuration options appear to be present in each of the 3 files.

What is the intended purpose of each file?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across an answer here:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-metadata/config-kraft.html

- `broker.properties` - An example of the settings to use when the server is a broker only.
- `controller.properties` - An example of the settings to use when the server is a controller only.
- `server.properties` - An example of the settings to use when the server is both a broker and a controller. This configuration is not supported for production use.